# How to save a user name in the form with Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I haven't coded in Rails for a while so struggling a bit.

When a user created a post via a form I made, how can I have the users user name be automatically saved with the post.

I use Facebook Omniauth for authentication.

When I for example search\index all the posts the name is on that post.

What will the code for the show page be?

Here is my index page code:

```
Name:
?????
From:
<%= post.from %>
To:
<%= post.to %>
Date:
<%= post.date %>
```

The Form:

```
      <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :name %>
      <%= ? %>
      </div>
      <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :from %>
      <%= f.text_field :from, :class => 'address-picker-input' %>
      </div>
      <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :to %>
      <%= f.text_field :to, :class => 'address-picker-input' %>
      </div>
      <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :date %>
      <%= f.text_field :date, :class=> "field shorter"  %>
      </div>
```

The controller:

```
       def create
       @post = current_user.posts.build(params[:post])
```

Comment: Post the form and the controller action for it to get the best help.

Comment: Plz provide snippet of code

Answer (score 1):

In your controller you are passing posts from your current user:

```
def create
   @post = current_user.posts.build(params[:post])
end
```

Just add a line and pass the user info:

```
@user_info = current_user.user_info
# => included data: name, nickname, first_name, last_name
```

Check the [docs](https://github.com/intridea/omniauth/wiki/Auth-Hash-Schema) for more data you can work with.

Finally, you could easily implement the wished data in your view:

```
<div class="username">
<%= @user.name %>
</div>
```

Comment: I think I found the answer: In the view just put in: <%=post.user.name%>

Comment: looks good, I also updated my answer ;) check if it worked...

Btw, which omniauth are you using?